# Android set one TextView's textsize equal to another's

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have a textview who's size is being set based on android's autoSizeTextType="uniform". I want to copy that size to two other text views.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    val firstButton = activity?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.b1)
    val secondButton = activity?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.b2)
    val thirdButton = activity?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.b3)

    if (firstButton != null) {
        secondButton?.textSize = firstButton.textSize
        thirdButton?.textSize = firstButton.textSize
    }
```

This, however, results in the text size of 2 and 3 being about 4x as large as the first. Anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? I'm guessing it is getting some sort of dpi scaled size, but I'm not sure how to get the correct size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView.getTextSize()` returns [size in pixels](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView?hl=en#gettextsize), but `setTextSize()` interpret parameter as scaled pixels (sp). There's [setTextSize() overload](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView?hl=en#settextsize_1) which accept text size and unit. In your case unit should be `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX`.

```
secondButton?.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, firstButton.textSize)
```

Comment: This is helpful, but now it looks like it is setting it to the original size of the first text view, before autoSizeTextType="uniform" takes effect. I am calling this in the onResume method. Is there some callback for textsizechanged or something similar in which I could place the code so that it happens after the first text got resized?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What if 2nd and 3rd buttons will have autosize too? :) There's no direct callback, but probably something like this can be achieved with layout listener.

Comment: The second and third textViews do not have autosize. Essentially I have 3 textviews each of which needs to fit on one line and all of them need to be the same size. I know ahead of time that the first one will always be the longest, so I am using an autosize for it, and then want to copy that size to the other two lines. I'll look into doing it with a layout listener.